# Split Edge modifier split undesired edge

Tags: modifiers, shaders, edges

Here, is the model applied Edge Split modifier. Currently no sharp edges and split angle is 30 degrees.

[image]

Near the cursor, you can see that split edges in front slope, in red rectangle.

And this is the edit mode screenshot:

[image]

It seems nothing special to me, but why split edge coming through here?

I want to rid off those split edge. How do I remove that?

Comment: Maybe a split edge? Try unhiding all verts and removing doubles

Comment: @Leander Oh, thank you so much! It works now!